# Not able to clear browser memory, even if clearing all texture cache with pixi. I am using pixioverlay and react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js, react-leaflet

I am creating PIXI sprite using SVG, and in react hooks I am clearing all the texture cache and base cache, but it is not clearing browser memory.

Here is code for clearing all the cache and other resources.

```
      // unmount

         useEffect(
             () => () => {
                 if (pixiOverlay) {
                       pixiOverlay.utils.getContainer().removeChildren();
                 }
                for (const textureUrl in PIXI.utils.BaseTextureCache) {
                  delete PIXI.utils.BaseTextureCache[textureUrl];
                }
               for (const textureUrl in PIXI.utils.TextureCache) {
                  delete PIXI.utils.TextureCache[textureUrl];
               }
               PIXILoader.reset();
               
            },
            []
           );
```

Can any one please tell me, is there any way to clear memory when markers are destroyed.

Comment: did you used `() => () => {` instead of `() => {` by intend, or it's a mistake ?

Comment: No I have intentionally used it. It's a callback. This how it works in react hooks, to clear data.

Comment: did you tried `dispose()` also? like: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/nrga_1W3wADpVWexU0n1c

Comment: Yes,but its shows, clear() method not found. I an creating marker using **const marker= PIXILoader.resources[`marker_${jobId}`].texture **

Comment: And dispose() also not found,as we are not using graphics.I also tried                                     **pixiContainer.children.forEach(data => {
          data.destroy(true);
        })**   It also didn't work.

Comment: can you provide the code or a sample code? cause it's hard to debug without the code.

Comment: also check this: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/11781-is-there-a-cache-to-clear-that-im-missing/